# Set especific Mockery expectation only when needed

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, mockery

I've had this issue several times and want to know if I can solve it more easily.

I have some controller tests in Laravel 4 + Mockery:

```
public function testShow()
{
    $nestedView = 'pedidos.show';
    $this->registerNestedView($nestedView);


    $this->mock
        ->shouldReceive('find')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn($this->pedidoModelMock);
    $this->pedidoModelMock
        ->shouldReceive('getAttribute')
        ->atLeast()
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(1);
    $this->pedidoModelMock
        ->shouldReceive('getAttribute')
        ->once()
        ->with('pedidol')
        ->andReturn(new \Illuminate\Support\Collection());

    $this->call('GET', '/clientes/1/pedidos/1');

    $this->assertResponseOk();
    $this->assertViewHas('pageAttributes');
    $this->assertViewHas('contenido');
    $this->assertNestedViewHas($nestedView, 'pedido');
}
```

In my view, I have multiple lines similar to these:

```
          <div class="detail">
                <dt>Localidad</dt>
                <dd>{{{$pedido->loc}}}</dd>
            </div>
            <div class="detail">
                <dt>Provincia</dt>
                <dd>{{{$pedido->prov}}}</dd>
            </div>
```

so that's why I mock all those calls with

```
$this->pedidoModelMock
        ->shouldReceive('getAttribute')
        ->atLeast()
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(1);
```

The problem is I have this later in my code:

```
@foreach ($pedido->pedidoline as $line)
    <tr>
        <td>{{{$line->code}}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

So I need to return a different value **just for that specific call**. As you can see in the first code snippet, I've tried combining the general expectation with the specific:

```
$this->pedidoModelMock
        ->shouldReceive('getAttribute')
        ->atLeast()
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(1);
    $this->pedidoModelMock
        ->shouldReceive('getAttribute')
        ->once()
        ->with('pedidol')
        ->andReturn(new \Illuminate\Support\Collection());
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I am forced to write an especific expectation for every single call to getAttribute to be able to set that one. Is there any easier way?

Comment: I haven't found a way to do that and I've resorted to creating a collection of mocks. The good news is that you can tailor your mocks to, for example, return a small (or empty) collection - say, a collection with one element. That will make creating mocks a little easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking in the #mockery IRC channel, I got this answer, and it works:ç

Instead of using plain `->andReturn()`, `->andReturnUsing()` (which accepts a closure) can be used, like this:

```
->andReturnUsing(function ($attr) {
            if ($attr == 'pedidoline') {
                return new \Illuminate\Support\Collection();
            }
            return 1;
        });
```